# A script to find all the users who are executing a specific program

Tags: bash, scripting

I've written the bash script (`searchuser`) which should display all the users who are executing a specific program or a script (at least a bash script). But when searching for scripts fails because the command the SO is executing is something like `bash scriptname`.

This script acts parsing the `ps` command output, it search for all the occurrences of the specified program name, extracts the user and the program name, verifies if the program name is that we're searching for and if it's it displays the relevant information (in this case the user name and the program name, might be better to output also the PID, but that is quite simple). The verification is accomplished to reject all lines containing program names which contain the name of the program but they're not the program we are searching for; if we're searching `gedit` we don't desire to find `sgedit` or `gedits`.

Other issues I've are:

- I would like to avoid the use of a tmp file.
- I would like to be not tied to GNU extensions.

The script has to be executed as:

```
root# searchuser programname <invio>
```

The script `searchuser` is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
search=$1

tmp=`mktemp`
ps -aux | tr -s ' ' | grep "$search" > $tmp

while read fileline
do
    user=`echo "$fileline" | cut -f1 -d' '`
    prg=`echo "$fileline" | cut -f11 -d' '`
    prg=`basename "$prg"`
    if [ "$prg" = "$search" ]; then
        echo "$user - $prg"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    fi
done < $tmp

if [ $i = 0 ]; then
    echo "No users are executing $search"
fi

rm $tmp

exit $i
```

Have you suggestion about to solve these issues?

Comment: Why don't you use `pgrep`?

Comment: Also, the temporary file here is completely unnecessary. `while read ...; do ...; done < <(ps aux ...)` would avoid it (if one _were_ to parse `ps`, which is bad practice).

Comment: pgrep doesn't give me the user!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, but you can get the user (and any other metadata you want -- command line, environment variables, etc) from the PID via procfs more reliably than dealing with `ps`.

Comment: ...well, "more reliably" in some senses. Anything that isn't atomic is a risk, but if you want a 100% atomic means of querying this information, you'd need to use sysdig (http://www.sysdig.org/).

Comment: BTW, `echo $filename` is bad juju -- won't always give you the exact filename unmodified. `echo "$filename"` is slightly better, and `printf '%s\n' "$filename"` even moreso (though both are only workable assuming no newlines in your filename, which isn't always a safe assumption), but even better is a parameter expansion.

Comment: Then I understand a thing that I've forgotten the use of ( ps -aux ) ...

Comment: Where's $filename? In the script is $fileline!

Comment: The quoting (or lack thereof) is what matters, not the exact variable name. :)

Comment: ...check what `echo $fileline` does if `fileline` contains a literal `*` in it surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: Also, `[ $prg == $search ]` is broken; look at what happens when either left or right side is empty or contains a space. Also, `==` isn't valid in POSIX test; it's a GNU extension, so won't work on all platforms. Use `[ "$prg" = "$search" ]` instead.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. But fileline contains a line extract from the ps output !

Comment: If you didn't mind using GNU extensions, by the way -- `stat --format=%U /proc/"$pid"` gives the user who owns the process with a given PID.

Comment: "But fileline contains the line of ps !" - So? `ps` output can contain literal asterisks. It can contain *anything*, if a program overwrites its own argv array (which is legal, and which many programs do).

Comment: Ok, I understand that is completely not the correct way!!!

Answer (score 1):

One approach might looks like such:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a pids < <(pgrep -x -- "$1"; printf '\0')
if (( ! ${#pids[@]} )); then
  echo "No users are executing $1"
fi

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  # build a more accurate command line than the one ps emits
  args=( )
  while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do
    args+=( "$arg" )
  done </proc/"$pid"/cmdline
  (( ${#args[@]} )) || continue # exited while we were running
  printf -v cmdline_str '%q ' "${args[@]}"

  user=$(stat --format=%U /proc/"$pid") || continue # exited while we were running
  printf '%q - %s\n' "$user" "${cmdline_str% }"
done
```

Unlike the output from `ps`, which doesn't distinguish between `./command "some argument"` and `./command "some" "argument"`, this will emit output which correctly shows the arguments run by each user, *with quoting which will re-run the given command correctly*.

Comment: My problem is also that pgrep seems to work searching substrings, then if I have a process named gedits and I search for gedit it found a PID that is not what I want. That is one of the reason why I've tried to write a script.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, sounds like you're using an old version. 11 minutes ago I updated it to use the `pgrep -x` argument, which fixes that. (Oddly, that's over 10 minutes before your comment; perhaps you need to reload the page?).

Comment: I'd suggest using the new code as it is in entirety, rather than just making that one change, to make sure that any other fixes from the original are also included.

Comment: It's completely different ... Ok! Is very cryptic for me ... :p I've to study it!

Comment: I'd like to find something less tied to GNU.

Comment: If you want to ditch `stat --format`, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087 would be a place to start. That's really the only GNUism here (there are other bashisms, but, well, you tagged the question bash; if you don't want bashisms, tag `sh` or `shell`).

Comment: (now, if you said "less tied to Linux", we'd need to be rid of procfs, and then we'd be back to hackery with `ps`).

Comment: I know, excuse me! ... I've better specified in function of my purposes, but your reply is very intersting!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
ps -e -o user,comm | egrep "^[^ ]+ +$1$" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u
```

*** Addendum ***

This statement:

```
ps -e -o user,pid,comm | egrep "^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s*$1$" | while read a b; do echo $a; done | sort | uniq -c
```

or this one:

```
ps -e -o user,pid,comm | egrep "^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s*sleep$" | xargs -L1 echo | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

shows the number of process instances by user.

Comment: Why did you change the egrep expression?

Comment: Is the line you are suggesting only for GNU use or it may run on other UNIX systems?

Comment: I'm using: `ps -e -o user,pid,comm | egrep " $1$"` to ouput also the pid. It seems a good way ... `sort` is not useful because I need to know all the processes the user is executing ... `sort` may be used to sort the users! The only thing remains is to count the processes, but the loop in my script may use your `ps` avoiding other verifications.

Comment: Another issue is that I've also to search for scripts (at least bash scripts) and this command doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: This is a fairly reasonable approach (within the bounds of what can be done with `ps` -- so no reconstructing command line argument boundaries/quoting/etc, and no support for matching processes which change their `argv[0]`), and as currently implemented it would behave badly if searching for a process with a name that contained regex characters -- for instance, `+` signs. Still, if portability were a primary concern, I might use this.